# Salesforce Assign Cases created by Standard user to Community Users

Tags: apex, community

I have created a salesforce customer Community with Licence Customer Community user. I have some cases in my org which have owner as Salesforce administrator or other salesforce standard user. Now the requirement is to transfer these cases to community users. is it possible? If i am try to change the owner from system administrator, it is not showing community users under portal user dropdown??

If salesforce doesnt allow this, is there any way to assign the cases from queue to community users?? that will be also ok.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign Cases to a Customer Community user. You can only to this for Partner Community users.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Do you have any other option to implement this type of requirement??

Comment: Why would you want to assign to a customer? The owner of the case would be the one resolving it, not the one logging it. SF has a standard lookup to Account & Contact to capture the logger of a case.

Comment: In the communities we will not have customers but we will have some contractors who will solve those cases. thats why.